# How to Build the required JSON Format in ios?

Tags: ios, json

This is my json response:

```
{
"projects": [
{
"id": 8,
"name": "Andriod APP",
"identifier": "andriod-app",
"description": "",
"status": 1,
"is_public": true,
"created_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
"updated_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"
},
],
"total_count": 8,
"offset": 0,
"limit": 25
}
```

1.I had created drop down and shows the project name only in drop down(requirement).

2.On selecting the project name in table view have to get project id also.achieved through this piece of code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

projdict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[projdict setObject:[self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"data"];
```

The contents of data is:

```
{
data ={
"created_on" = "2015-06-24T11:01:11Z";
description = "";
id = 3;
identifier = fotonation;
"is_public" = 1;
name = Fotonation;
status = 1;
"updated_on" = "2015-06-24T11:01:11Z";
};
}
```

From this response i got the project id of the selected project name.

```
projid = [[projdict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Then i created the dictionary:

```
 proj_id = @"id";
 proj_name = @"name";
 test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:projid,proj_id, projname,proj_name, nil];
```

i want to get json format like :

```
{
“project”:{
“id”:”3”,
”name”:”fotonation
}
```

For that i had done like this:

```
NSDictionary * test1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Project",test, nil];
```

Response for test1 is :

```
{
{
id = 3;
name = Fotonation;
} = Project;
}

NSError * error;
NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:test1 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

on this i am getting error on nsdata it shows the error:

invalid (non-string) key in json dictionary.

3.I kept all the values in the didrowselect is it possible to pass the values to any other method or globally?

4.any article or tutorial for JSON formatting and Json request in ios?

Comment: the `= Project` is the problem here - but I am confused by your post, what data comes from where an so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got your objects and keys reversed in this call to `initWithObjectsAndKeys`:

```
NSDictionary *test1 = 
  [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Project",test, nil];
```

In the method `initWithObjectsAndKeys`, the object comes first, then the key, which is confusing.

You're passing in @"Project" as the object, and `test` (a dictionary) as the key.

If you're going to use the method `initWithObjectsAndKeys` then you want

```
NSDictionary *test1 = 
  [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
   test, @"Project", nil];
```

However, I suggest using modern object literal syntax, like this:

```
NSDictionary *test1 = @{@"project": test};
```

It's both more compact and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSDictionary * test1 = @{@"projects": @[@{@"id": @8,
                                          @"name": @"Andriod APP",
                                          @"identifier": @"andriod-app",
                                          @"description": @"",
                                          @"status": @1,
                                          @"is_public": @1,
                                          @"created_on": @"2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
                                          @"updated_on": @"2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"

                                          }],
                         @"total_count": @8,
                         @"offset": @0,
                         @"limit": @25
                         };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:test1 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```